# How to discord.Invite (see how many members in a given invitation)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a bot for Discord, but
I'm having trouble making an accountant of invitations (people who enter a certain invitation)

In this way, it always returns None

```
    invite = await client.invites_from(message.channel.server)
        for x in invite:
    if x.inviter == message.author:
        uses_link = await client.get_invite(x)
        print(uses_link.uses) # This returns None
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Client.get_invite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_invite) coroutine accesses the [`GET Invite`](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#get-invite) endpoint of the Discord API ([See the source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/http.py#L556)).  That endpoint seems to return a Discord [`Invite` object](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#invite-object).  Critically, that object doesn't include the [Invite metadata object](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/invite#invite-metadata-object) which is where the `Invite.uses` field comes from.

Thankfully, the [`Client.invites_from`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.invites_from) coroutine returns a list of `Invite` objects that *are* calculated using the Invite metadata (from the [`GET Guild Invites` endpoint](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-invites)).  You can just use those directly.

```
invites = await client.invites_from(message.channel.server)
for invite in invite:
    if invite.inviter == message.author:
        print(invite.uses)
```

Comment: OMG TNKS <3


you helped me a lot. 
Thank you for the explanation